# Slug issue on spree product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am facing the issue of editing a product slug and then the product isn't opening up again . Steps to reproduce -

1) Adding a custom slug field on Spree Product

2) Editing the Product

3) Updating the slug

4) The show page says product not found

On further digging , the slug comes in the url due to which proper redirection isn't taking place .

I did an override on Product edit controller by making a decorator

```
Spree::Admin::ProductsController.class_eval do

    def edit
       @product = Spree::Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

The slugs are updated in the database as well , but i think it isn't redirecting after the slug gets added in the url . Any help in this regard would be much appreciated .

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes , every 5 minutes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , so this issue got solved and how . It seems that friendly_id did some changes to it's latest version that you need to follow as well to work with spree . Following is the change i did

Before

```
 friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]
```

After

```
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```